# Laravel 5.7: Eloquent orderBy related model as well as using whereHas condition

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have a model `OptionGroup` that has a related model `Option` which, in turn has a related model `Attribute`.

I'd like to get all the OptionGroups with their Options where the Option has a particular attribute (`product_id`) value and then order everything another value (`default`) within the Attribute model.

In my controller:

```
$optionGroups = OptionGroup::with(['options' => function($query) use ($product) {
            $query->whereHas('attributes', function($q) use ($product) {
                $q->where('product_id', $product->id);

                // Ideally here:
                // $q->orderBy('default', 'desc');
            });
        }])
        ->orderBy('sort_order', 'desc')
        ->get();
```

I've tried various eloquent scopes to try and apply the `orderBy()` on the model but without success.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What exactly are you trying to order? As of now your query will return a collection of OptionGroup, each loaded with Options relation. What should be ordered?

Comment: I'd like to order everything by the `default` field on the Attribute model.

Comment: How do you expect that to work if an `OptionGroup` has many `Options` and one `Option` has many `Attributes`? Which `default` value of all the attributes that are somewhat related to an `OptionGroup` would you use to sort?

Comment: I'm hoping to find all the `Attributes` with a given `product_id` then sort them in descending order by the `default` column. The `whereHas` is trying to narrow the number of `Attributes` returned (and works bar the ordering).

Comment: Ok, one step back please. Do you want to load all `OptionGroups` with all `Options` and their `Attributes`? And the `Attributes` per `OptionGroup` should be sorted? Or should the whole `OptionGroups` list be sorted by the decendent attributes?

Comment: That wont work, you'll need a different criteria to order OptionGroup.

Comment: I'd like to load all the `OptionGroups` and all their `Options` where that `Option` has an `Attribute` with a given `product_id`. I then want to sort the `Options` within an `OptionGroup` by the `default` field on the `Attribute`. Eg: an `OptionGroup` could be Size and have multiple `Options` such as Small, Medium, Large but each `Option` can have multiple `Attributes` such as Price because of variations in combinations of `OptionGroups`.

Comment: Yeah but that's not going to work. You cannot sort a parent table by a child table attribute. The only way to do is to only load a very specific option with exactly one attribute (i.e. `inner join`). But yeah...

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The following query will give you all `OptionGroups` that have at least one `Option` which has an `Attribute` that belongs to a given product (determined by the `product_id`). The query will then also only egaer load all `Options` and their `Attributes` with the given `product_id`. But sorting on a child relation is not possible due to ambiguity:

```
$optionGroups = OptionGroup::query()
    ->whereHas('options.attribute' => function ($query) use ($product) {
        $query->where('product_id', $product->id);
    })
    ->with(['options.attribute' => function ($query) use ($product) {
        $query->where('product_id', $product->id);
    }])
    ->get();
```